# Is it possible to add a margin to a p:first-line

Tags: css, pseudo-class

Why I can't add a margin to the first line of my p like this ?

```
p:first-line{
 color:red; /* ok */
 margin-bottom:20px; /* nothing */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xtb5M/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the **[W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-elements/%3afirst-line)**, the margin property doesn't apply to the `first-line` selector:

The ::first-line pseudo-element is similar to an inline-level element, but with certain restrictions. The following CSS properties apply to a ::first-line pseudo-element:

- font properties
- color property
- background properties
- ‘word-spacing’
- ‘letter-spacing’
- ‘text-decoration’
- ‘vertical-align’
- ‘text-transform’
- ‘line-height’

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. `<p>` are block level by default.

Answer (score -1):

You could fake it with line-height

```
p{
    margin-top:-10px;
}

p:first-line{
  color:red;  
  line-height: 40px;      
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/Y9M28/